# pygsheets data written to gsheets with formulaic chars takes data as formulas

Tags: python-3.x, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, pygsheets

When writing data to gsheets with pygsheets - one of my values contains a `+` char. e.g. `+myvalue`

When then exporting the data, I get the `#NAME?` output, instead of the background value.[image: #NAME?], of course the formula bar contains the right value.[image: +myvalue]

This is not completely unexpected, however - when use the sheets method and manually import a CSV containing these values - the `#NAME?` error is not displayed, and instead I can see the +myvalue in the field. (Unless I edit it.)

This is my code for "importing" the csv - of course it's just reading the csv and loading values:

```
# Authorise with GSheets Service Account
gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_file=service_account_file)

# Open spreadsheet
sh = gc.open_by_key(spreadsheet_key)

# Open Worksheet
#wks = sh.add_worksheet(spreadsheet_hosts_worksheet) # Create Worksheet
wks = sh.worksheet_by_title(worksheet_name)

# Generate list "data" with Values from CSV
with open(inputFile, 'r') as f:
  #reader = csv.reader(f, skipinitialspace=True, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
  reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
  data = list(reader)

# Empty Worksheet
wks.clear()

# Append Values
wks.update_values(crange='A1', values=data)

# Freeze Top Row
wks.frozen_rows=1
```

Can I change the updating method, so that it takes formulas like text - same way a `CSV import` function on `GSheets` would?

My sample data:

```
['host_name', 'alias', 'address', 'parents', 'use', 'display_name', 'hostgroups', 'contacts', '_ADDINFO', '_SNOWGROUP', '_RTTCRIT', '_RTTWARN', 'contact_groups', 'notes', 'notes_url', 'check_command', 'first_notification_delay', 'check_interval', 'max_check_attempts', 'retry_interval', 'config_filename']
['host', 'destiny islands', '1.1.1.1', 'host.mypalace.com,host.mapalace2.com', 'tmpl_network_device', 'Gingerbread lane', 'hgrp_grandad', '+myvalue', 'ACTION - Don't forget to smile', 'test', '70', '20', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '/folder/filename']
```

Comment: In order to correctly understand your question, can I ask you about it? You want to put the formulas to cells. Is my understanding correct? And what is ``+myvalue``?

Comment: I would like to put the value `+myvalue` into the cells, without it appearing as a formula. So when I view the spreadsheet, the field would say `+myvalue` instead of `#NAME?`. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I could understand about your result. So I posted an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using `parse=False`?

When I saw [the script](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/pygsheets/sheet.html?highlight=values_batch_update), the default is `parse=True`. In this case, `valueInputOption` uses `USER_ENTERED`. When `parse=False` is used, `valueInputOption` uses `RAW`. By this, `+myvalue` doesn't `#NAME?`.

#### Modified script:

```
wks.update_values(crange='A1', values=[['+myvalue']])  # ---> #NAME? is put in a cell "A1"

wks.update_values(crange='A2', values=[['+myvalue']], parse=False)  # ---> +myvalue is put in a cell "A2"
```

#### References:

- [Source code for pygsheets.sheet](https://pygsheets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/pygsheets/sheet.html?highlight=values_batch_update)
- [ValueInputOption](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/ValueInputOption)

Comment: @itChi I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.